# How to enable video autoplay on Fire Tablet? Solution can include hacking this device

Tags: video, amazon-kindle-fire

**I need a way of having a Fire Tablet autoplay videos through a web browser.**

The videos in question are iframed YouTube videos, but if necessary they can be put on Vimeo, or hosted on a server I control.

Essentially, **I want the desktop browser experience running on a Fire tablet**. I do not need it to be a universal solution for all mobiles, *just this particular tablet.*

I know FireOS is based on Android, and I am hoping that there is a way to hack it so that it allows this functionality. But I know nothing about Android at the moment, so hopefully one can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after a few hours of tinkering around, I figured out how to do this.

You have to use HTML5 video, so that is one thing. Then you need a mobile browser that supports auto-play, so Firefox needs to get installed.

This is tricky, because you need the Google Play Store, so you need to install that. That requires going into developer mode, then installing a script that will install Google Play. Then you can install Firefox and voila, problem solved.

I went ahead and rooted it, blocked ads, and blocked updates as well because it works way better that way.

This link below shows a video on how to root your Fire tablet and do everything I did: [Amazon Fire 5th gen Rooted on Fire OS 5 1 1 with SuperTool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVv1D_LNLTg&feature=youtu.be)